# Checkbox input is selected only when clicked outside

Tags: html

I have an issue with HTML which is generated via the GWT framework.
It seems that the checkbox can be selected only outside of input.

```html
  <label for="gwt-id">
        <input type="checkbox" id="gwt-id" />
        <span class="someclass"></span>
    </label>
```

As you can see, there is `for` property. When I remove it then the checkbox can't be selected at all.
I didn't copy styles, because even after removing them it does not work. Any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: 'Checkbox' is spelled wrong :) Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @Sjors Nope, it was just my type :)

Comment: Hm okay, then it can even be a css or javascript issue. Could you isolate the problem a bit more, maybe setup a codepen example so we can have a better understanding of at what's happening?

Comment: The checkbox works in the snippet and also on my local file

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element).
But it will require some code.
[Something like this:](https://www.blustemy.io/detecting-a-click-outside-an-element-in-javascript/)

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    var flyoutElement = document.getElementById('flyout-example'),
        targetElement = evt.target;  // clicked element

    do {
        if (targetElement == flyoutElement) {
            // This is a click inside. Do nothing, just return.
            document.getElementById("flyout-debug").textContent = "Clicked inside!";
            return;
        }
        // Go up the DOM
        targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
    } while (targetElement);

    // This is a click outside.
    document.getElementById("flyout-debug").textContent = "Clicked outside!";
});
```

If you want, you can use an [external library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/click-outside).
Or with [Vue.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-click-outside) and [React.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-click-outside)